# AngularJS - How can I filter through a nested json array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

AngularJS newbie here. Here is a JSON file that I've been working on and what I'm trying to do is to filter the search by ingredient using AngularJS. Help please?

```
{
    "id": 01,
    "recipe-name": "Fried Fish",
    "ing": {
        "i1": "1 fish",
        "i2": "1 egg",
        "i3": "1\/2 cup flour",
        "i4": "salt and pepper",
        "i5": "chili leaves"
    }
}
```

Here's my code for the filtered results

```
    <div class="results" ng-repeat="r in recipes | filter:q.ing">
```

Comment: You should go for custom fitler then..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a filter.

You just need to `ng-repeat` through the `recipes.ing` nested object.

```
<div class="results" ng-repeat="r in recipes.ing">
    <p>{{r}}</p>
</div>
```

Simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zq39zspc/1/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: If it solved the problem for you, please accept and vote it up :)